# SQL how can I use a variable for the string "1-3" in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm converting a program written in vb6 that has run flawlessly for 18 years, due to MSoft's problems with ocx components. I'm trying to convert from vb6 to Visual Basic in Studio 2019. Also trying to do this in SQL, using a string variable in the Where clause of a query on a MSAcess 365 database. The string consists of one or more numbers, a hyphen, and one or more numbers. The 'Cite' field in the database is a text field.

I've looked at all of the suggested answers on StackOverflow, along with numerous DuckDuck searches. I cannot find any examples where this worked. I've tried making the variable into a character array, passing the first number, then the hyphen, then the last number. I've tried various combinations of escape characters, single quotes, double quotes, Declares, brackets, etc etc.

THIS WORKS

```
    Using myConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\work\temp\va_cod.accdb")

        myConnection.Open()

        Dim queryNovice As New OleDbCommand(cmdText:="SELECT ID, FileNum, Name FROM Level6 Where Cite = '1-3'", myConnection)

        Using reader As OleDbDataReader = queryNovice.ExecuteReader()
```

THIS DOES NOT WORK

```
    Using myConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\work\temp\va_cod.accdb")

        Dim strCite As String = "1-3"

        myConnection.Open()

        Dim queryNovice As New OleDbCommand(cmdText:="SELECT ID, FileNum, Name FROM Level6 Where Cite = strCite", myConnection)

        Using reader As OleDbDataReader = queryNovice.ExecuteReader()
```

On the execute line of the version that's trying to use the variable the error message is "No value given for one or more required parameters." When I use '1-3' I get the correct result in a listbox. The data is the citation numbers of the statues of one state. The users might supply any one of 33,000 different citations, and many of the citations also include periods, parentheses, colons, and letters.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: take a look a parameter in select

Answer (score 0):

Your query contains the literal strCite.

Change it to something like

```
  Dim queryNovice As New OleDbCommand(cmdText:="SELECT ID, FileNum, Name FROM Level6 Where Cite = '" + strCite + "'", myConnection)
```

or use Parameters as scaisEdge suggested - which would be more secure.

Comment: . . You should be showing how to use parameters.  That is the right answer to the problem.

Comment: Schneider's fix worked. VStudio was giving error messages about string constants ending in double quotes. Quote Apostrophe Quote works.